# how to find any prime' a' that satisfies the congruence $a^{24}\equiv 6a+2 (mod 13) $?

Tags: group-theory

I can't understand well the congruence modulo in group theory ... So help me here.
how to find any prime' a'  that satisfies the congruence $a^{24}\equiv 6a+2 \pmod {13}  $ ?

Comment: Do you know Fermat's theorem?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: yes but unable to apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Fermat's little theorem $a^{p-1}\equiv 1 \space(p)$ if $(a,p)=1$ and $p$ is a prime number. So $a^{13-1}=a^{12}\equiv1\space (13)$.
Then you can use this as follow: $a^{24}=a^{2*12}\equiv 1 \space (13)$ so $1\equiv 6a+2 \space (13) \Leftrightarrow\space 6a\equiv-1\space (13) \Leftrightarrow \space a\equiv-1\cdot(-2) \space mod(13)$.

Hope this help you.